# Printing Associative Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, associative-array

I have declared an associative array and now want to print it:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, int> m;

    m["Peter"] = 4;
    m["John"] = 3;
    m["Katie"] = 3;

    map<string, int>::iterator curr,end;

    for(curr = m.begin(), end = m.end(); curr != end; curr++) {
        printf("%s : %i\n", curr->first, curr->second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error from my compiler:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:24: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘const struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
```

And surprise suprise - it's true - call aborts at runtime...

But I don't know why... What should I fix? What exactly mean "through ‘...’" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
    printf("%s : %i\n", curr->first.c_str(),  curr->second);
```

The `c_str()` method convert `std::string` to a c-style string (`char*`).

the `...` refers to [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)'s [vararg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D) prototype:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

which won't support passing c++ objects.

---

BTW, you should use `++curr` instead of `curr++`. This is some c++ magic that prevent duplicating a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::cout` in C++, especially with STL :

```
std::cout << curr->first << " : " << curr->second << std::endl;
```

By the way, no need to define yet another variable called 'end'. So you may instead rewrite your `for` loop like this:

```
 for(map<string, int>::iterator curr = m.begin(); curr != m.end() ; curr++) 
 {
       std::cout << curr->first << " : " << curr->second << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calculating the end only once in cases where the length of the container does not change (as in this case).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that varargs functions (functions that take an unbounded number of arguments, like printf) do not play well with C++ objects.  In the "Good" ol' Days of pure C, varargs worked just fine because there was no concept of an object with state.  You could just copy the bits from some struct or other object around as you saw fit without running into any problems.  In C++, though, objects have constructors and destructors which they use to control internal state.  You can't just blindly copy the bits from a C++ object someplace else and expect to get a working copy.

The problem with varargs functions is that inside the varargs function, the typical way that the function retrieves an argument off the arguments list is to just blindly copy the bytes over.  This breaks all sorts of invariants, and so the C++ specification specifically says that this results in undefined behavior.  In this case, "undefined behavior" means "the compiler will terminate the program before something really bad happens to you."

The reason that you're getting this error is that one of the arguments you're passing to printf is a `std::string`, which is a bona fide C++ object with nontrivial constructors, destructors, and copy functions.  The compiler is telling you that this isn't okay for the reasons I've mentioned above.  To fix this, you'll need to pass something else into the function, as suggested by some of the other posters here.  Alternatively, you should just use `std::cout` to do the printing, since it's fully type-safe and doesn't use scary varargs functions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to printf std::string class. Use cout, printf works only with integrial types

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C and C++, you are calling C language `stdio` `print` function with an object of type `const struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >` (this is the type of `curr->first` map's key - string)

Try this

```
cout <<  curr->first <<  curr->second << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

as a side note, there is no real reason to use a special `end` variable for checking the end of the container: first, `end()` is usually an inline function just returning the end indication, and second, any decent compiler would optimize this out anyway. I'd write your code like this:

```
typedef map<string, int> Score;

Score sc;
// ... set values ...

for(Score::const_iteator curr = sc.begin(); curr != sc.end(); ++curr) {
    cout << curr->first << ": " << curr->second;
}
```